# Modeling collaborators' cursors in Google Drive Realtime API

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I have a CollaborativeString.  I'd like to display each Collaborator's cursor position as they are editing it.  I can model a cursor using an IndexReference into the string.  And I can allow each Collaborator to maintain their own cursor model inside a CollaborativeMap from Collaborator IDs to cursors.

But, what happens when a Collaborator leaves?  Since there's no server component, I guess the other users have to handle cleaning dead items out of the map?  And what if everyone has left, and there's nobody to clean up the last one?  I guess it'd have to be cleaned up by whoever joins next.

I suppose it's not so bad to have all users listening on CollaboratorLeftEvent and racing to delete the corresponding item, since deleting the same item twice shouldn't be much of a problem.  Is it a problem?  And then I can make another check over the list if you join and you are the first Collaborator, or every time a Collaborator joins so I don't have to worry about faulty clients messing it up.

Am I overlooking a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically have the right idea.  You should listen for collaborator leave/join events and update what is being tracked appropriately.  As you say, its OK for multiple people to make the changes for leave, as they will do the same thing.

The [Realtime Playground](https://github.com/googledrive/realtime-playground) has an example of this.